# Best way to sort/compare through multiple documents?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I am using numpy and am working on spyder.

Let us assume that we have some sort of 'scan' that provides us with GPS locations of houses in some city.

This scan, once finished, results in a .txt file which contains (x,y)-coordinates which correspond to the GPS location of said houses.

Let's say I am given around 40 sets of (x,y) coordinates in the FIRST file.

Now imagine that we run the same 'scan' again which results in a second file.
In a perfect world, both files would contain the same coordinates, in exactly the same order.

But, (!) and this is the issue, it can happen that sometimes a 'scan' can MISS a house such that file1 would contain 40 (x,y) coordinate pairs but file2 would contain 39 (x,y) pairs. (see below)

Notice that below scan nr2 has missed house nr.3 and instead house nr.4 got labeled as 3. From now on the two scan lists are 'out of sync' by 1, which is something I need to adress.

Raw File1:

```
1        Location: 28802.6    ,   128823.3
2        Location: 47405.0    ,   74931.0
3        Location: 49952.4    ,   117478.8
4        Location: 50901.7    ,   42166.5
...
40       Location: 143924.5   ,   143847.7
41       Location: 143821.0   ,   143845.4
42       Location: 141584.4   ,   143842.4
```

Raw File2:

```
1        Location: 28802.6    ,   128823.3
2        Location: 47405.0    ,   74931.0
3        Location: 50901.7    ,   42166.5
...
39       Location: 143924.5   ,   143847.7
40       Location: 143821.0   ,   143845.4
41       Location: 141584.4   ,   143842.4
```

Wanted Resulting array1/list1:

```
[28802.6, 128823.3],
[47405.0, 74931.0],
[49952.4, 117478.8],
[50901.7, 42166.5],
...
[143924.5,   143847.7,],
[143821.0,   143845.4],
[141584.4,   143842.4]
```

Wanted Resulting array2/list2:

```
[28802.6, 128823.3],
[47405.0, 74931.0],
[0, 0],
[50901.7, 42166.5],
...
[143924.5,   143847.7,],
[143821.0,   143845.4],
[141584.4,   143842.4]
```

What I ultimately would want to achieve is to insert the (x,y) coordinates of each file into 2d arrays or 2d lists but in such a way that the rows in BOTH arrays correspond to the SAME houses.

Such that I know that if both scans have scanned house nr.2 (which for now is the case) that row number 2 in array1 and row number 2 in array2 contain the (x,y) coordinates corresponding to the same house.

And in case file1 contains coordinates from house 3 which are NOT included in file2, which means that scan2 must have missed that house I'd ideally want my code to enter the coordinates from scan 1 into row number 3 of array1 but since scan2 has no results here, enter only zeros in array2 row 3, as seen above.

And finally, since now I hope I made my goal clear....the kicker: What if I have more than 2 scans? Like 3 or 5 for example?
And also keep in mind it can very well be that file1 will MISS a house which will be included in file2. Everything is possible.

I am not looking for a full solution, this post is more a question about how to approach this issue. Because if I will use for-loops this will get convoluted very fast. I am kind of hoping for some special python command that could help me out here.

Again I am using numpy and am working on spyder.

Comment: I think the more fundamental question is how/why a house can be missed on a second scan. Further, is it possible that a house comes up with coordinates that differ by a few metres (i.e. in say the 4th decimal place) on subsequent scans?

Comment: 1. Let us assume that the camera used by the satellite is non-ideal and sometimes just misses a house here or there.
2. Sadly, you are totally right! The exact coordinates of a single house can differ slightly from scan to scan. But since this is a whole other issue I have not mentioned that in the OP. Sorry! 

Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I was told by a friend that I could break the entire scanned area down into smaller squares (for example 10x10) and use these squares to further analyze the house locations. What do you think about that?

Comment: I think this type of thing is right up Fred's street @fmw42 Maybe he will have some useful insights.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you hash the coordinates (x,y) to produce a md5 string identifying each house.

```
import hashlib
coordinates = [28802.6, 128823.3]
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(",".join([str(n) for n in coordinates]).encode('utf-8'))
m.hexdigest()
```

Now each house can have a "name" and you don't need to worry about the indices of the houses in the arrays, you should actually hash the coordinates while reading the file, and save that information in the arrays. If you want to keep track of which houses went missing in which file, keep a list of all the generated hashes, and after it's done check in every array which hashes are missing, then you can insert them in the array with whatever value you want.

Comment: I don't think hashing the coordinates will work in the light of the comments above which indicate a house could be recorded at a slightly different lat/lon on each scan.

Comment: That sounds great but as MarkSetchell pointed out I forgot to mention that sometimes the exakt coordinates have a slight shift and as such are not identical.

I was suggested that I should use a grid i.e. break down the entire scanned area into 10x10 squares (for example) and evaluate how many houses are in each square. Any ideas how to do this? How to create a grid at all?